# AES encryption output length

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I am running this Java code for AES encryption:

```
byte[] iv = new byte[16];

SecretKey aesKey = new SecretKeySpec("hex key here", "AES");

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));

return cipher.doFinal("32 characters here ...".getBytes());
```

I am always getting a 48 bytes output but I am having a legacy system that is expecting a 32 bytes input. How could the output length be controlled ?

Note: I must use AES CBC

Comment: so you run the code above and the result from doFinal is 96 bytes?

Comment: Why do you expect 64 bytes output? "some text" will generate a single block output with PKCS#5 padding, and assuming you are using AES-256, it will be 32 bytes.

Comment: By using `getBytes()` without specifying a Charset you are relying on defaults, which is usually a mistake. Furthermore, there is no encoding I am aware of in which "some text" will result in even as many as 64 bytes of output, let alone 96.

Comment: How long is your plaintext input?  How long do you expect it to be after the PKCS#5 padding is added?  For a 64 byte output, you need an input of 48 to 63 bytes, inclusive.  Padding will increase that to 64 bytes.

Comment: @rossum sorry for providing the wrong input... the actual input is 32 bytes long

Comment: @Display Name: A 32 byte input will be 48 bytes after padding, two blocks padded out to three blocks.  A thought: is your legacy systen expecting a 64 **bit** input (i.e. DES or 3DES)?

Comment: @rossum: Indeed, I would expect it to be 48 bytes long, but I do not know why the legacy system is having it 32 bytes long... I must use AES CBC

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting 32+16 bytes because of the padding you are using.

Usually padding only fills-up the remaining bytes until the next cipher block is full. But in your case the plaintext uses already 2 blocks (2 * 16 byte). In such a case there is no space left to encode the information "no padding necessary". Therefore one additional cipher block containing only padding data has to be added.

May be the legacy system does not use padding. Try **"AES/CBC/NoPadding"**.